# How can I align a psuedo tag before text in a list?

Tags: css, alignment, pseudo-element

I'm trying to right align text in a list with a psuedo icon appearing right before it. The icon does appear before the text, but it's at the left edge of the list item. I'd like for it to appear right before the text.

Like this:

```
           ICON this is text
      ICON this is more text
ICON this is still more text
```

Right now, it appears like this:

```
ICON            this is text
ICON       this is more text
ICON this is still more text
```

Here's my code:

```
    ul {
        counter-reset: a;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 28px;
        li {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 0 12px 0.8em;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            list-style-type: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            float: right;
            text-align: right;
            &:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                left: -17px;
                width: 16px;
                height: 17px;
                margin-right: 8px;
                background: url('/images/checkmark.png') no-repeat left top;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried a couple of things, like adding 'display: inline-block' to the li items, but that didn't work.

I'll continue to try to a couple of things, but I'm not having any luck.

(I did figure out a way to get the results I wanted - I just didn't use the :before property and made the icons images. However, I'd like to use the :before tag, if possible.)

Thanks.

Comment: Must the icon be positioned absolutely? Without absolute, it works as designed: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyqLjW

Comment: That helped. By adding position: relative and display: inline-block to my :before property, the icons are positioned where I want them. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need either `position:relative` or `display:inline-block` for the pseudo-elements to display as you want. All that's needed is for them to have a `content` property set. By default their `display` is `inline`, which means they are displayed like any letter in text.

Comment: Absolute positioning wont work like that, unless you wanted a custom bullet to always be aligned in the same place.  I'm not sure using a `:before` or `:after` would work for you here since you need it in a dynamic place every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it with an extra p element and styled it like the way you wanr.

```css
  ul {
        counter-reset: a;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 28px;
 }
        li {
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 0 12px 0.8em;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            list-style-type: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: right;
      }
      li p {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
      }
      li p:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 2px;
                left: -17px;
                width: 16px;
                height: 17px;
                margin-right: 8px;
                background-color: red;
                /*background: url('http://pluspng.com/img-png/tick-box-png-checked-checkbox-icon-png-50-px-1600.png') no-repeat left top;*/
    }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><p>this is text</p>
</li>
<li><p>this is more text</p>
</li>
<li><p>this is still more text</p></li>
</ul>
```